# Do all varieties dominate a curve up to a ramified cover along a fixed divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a positive-dimensional variety over the complex numbers and let $D$ be a closed subscheme of $X$ of codimension one.

Under what conditions on $D$ does there exist a finite flat cover $Y$ of $X$ ramified  only along $D$ such that $Y$ maps non-trivially to a curve?

Comment: what do you mean by "ramified only along $D$"? Smooth away from $D$?